# Converting a String to Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object

How can I convert a string to object?
that is my data :

```
  "({"test1":[{"test2":55,"test":"15.06"},
   {"test3":55,"test4":"15.08"}]})"
```

Comment: Apply ``eval(...)`` on it. May be also understand the evils of eval.

Comment: I see that in that chain you have two objects will always be like this or will it be one? If it's an object you can use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Thanks  @KalEl  eval() give me  object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove the surrounding parentheses, you will get a JSON string, which can be converted to an object using [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var s = '({"test1":[{"test2":55,"test":"15.06"}, {"test3":55,"test4":"15.08"}]})',
    j = s.replace(/^\((.+)\)$/, '$1'),  //remove surrounding parentheses
    o = JSON.parse(j);

console.log(o);
```

Comment: thanks @RickHitchcock for this answer is  pretty good  acctually  eval() method solve this  problem .

Comment: `eval()` can be dangerous if you don't have control over the string.  Otherwise, it should work fine.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Ok i undestand thanks for this explanation  @RickHitchcock i use your code.